# Accessing all the files from a folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to access all the files from a certain folder so that I can get their path and put it into an array. Once I get this array, I'd like to use it in a react file and display its contents on a page. I had a general idea of looping through the folder but couldn't find a solution to my problem. Is there a way to do this, directly or maybe through a third-party package?

Comment: are you using node?

Comment: Welocme to SO. Please give us an idea of what you've already tried (code samle)

Comment: @Eduard Not entirely, I'm only using it for fs.readdir to extract the files from a certain folder and put their names into an array. The only issue I'm having is to essentially access that array, run through it, and print out each item on the front-end side of things (using react). I keep running into "Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function".

Comment: Cause fs is node.js module and it can’t be used in react

Comment: @Eduard is there something else I could use that could possibly help solve my issue?

Comment: Let's understand why do you need it on the frontend?

Comment: @Eduard I'd like to make a simple web app where a user is allowed to see the listing of files and able to delete them -- this is coupled with an upload feature (which I've already implemented).

Comment: I don’t know is this the best solution or not but ypu can do that all on the backend (node.js) and give APIs to fronted to get the list of folders and delete them

Comment: @Eduard Thanks! That helped me get on the right path to figure out the solution :D